# RegEx in vocabulary not working in sklearn TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, regex, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to calculate **tf-idf** of selected words in a corpus, but it didn't work when I use regex on selected words.

Below is the example I copied from another questions in stackoverflow and made small changes to reflect my question.

The code is pasted below. The code works if I write "chocolate" and "chocolates" separately but doesn't work if I write 'chocolate|chocolates'.

Can someone help me understand why and suggest possible solutions to this problem?

```
keywords = ['tim tam', 'jam', 'fresh milk', 'chocolate|chocolates', 'biscuit pudding']
corpus = {1: "making chocolate biscuit pudding easy first get your favourite biscuit chocolates", 2: "tim tam drink new recipe that yummy and tasty more thicker than typical milkshake that uses normal chocolates", 3: "making chocolates drink different way using fresh milk egg"}
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary = keywords, stop_words = 'english', ngram_range=(1,3))
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus.values())
feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()
corpus_index = [n for n in corpus]
rows, cols = tfs.nonzero()
for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
    print((feature_names[col], corpus_index[row]), tfs[row, col])
tfidf_results = pd.DataFrame(tfs.T.todense(), index=feature_names, columns=corpus_index).T
```

I expect the results to be:

```
('biscuit pudding', 1) 0.652490884512534
('chocolates', 1) 0.3853716274664007
('chocolate', 1) 0.652490884512534
('chocolates', 2) 0.5085423203783267
('tim tam', 2) 0.8610369959439764
('chocolates', 3) 0.5085423203783267
('fresh milk', 3) 0.8610369959439764
```

But, now it returns:

```
('biscuit pudding', 1) 1.0
('tim tam', 2) 1.0
('fresh milk', 3) 1.0
```

Comment: Should be `'chocolates|chocolate'`. Regex is matched left to right, so the shorter _forms_ of the root word should be last.

Comment: I guess my question is a bit confusing. Let me change it a little. If my target vocabulary is "pri" (a word I made up), but if I leave it as a string "pri" and the documents contains words such as "private", "price", then they will be tagged, but I only want "pri" this specific word so I wanted to write it as "\bpri\b", that's why I meant regex in my question. I didn't mean to group multiple terms together.

Comment: So ah, this `\b(?:pri|private|chocolate|chocolates)\b`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you are using `TfidfVectorizer` from scikit-learn. If you carefully read the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), nowhere it says that you can use regexes in your vocabulary, can you point to the question you mention you copied from?

If you want to group multiple terms together manually, you can specify a mapping instead of an iterable in your vocabular. For example:

```
keywords = {'tim tam':0, 'jam':1, 'fresh milk':2, 'chocolate':3, 'chocolates':3, 'biscuit pudding':4]
```

Notice how both `chocolate` and `chocolates` map to the same index.

Comment: Thanks for answering Josep, I guess my question is a bit confusing. Let me change it a little. If my target vocabulary is "pri" (a word I made up), but if I leave it as a string "pri" and the documents contains words such as "private", "price", then they will be tagged, but I only want "pri" this specific word so I wanted to write it as "\bpri\b", that's why I meant regex in my question. I didn't mean to group multiple terms together.